# How to convert a java.io list to a DataFrame in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using this code to get the list of files in a directory, and want to call to toDF method that works when converting lists to dataframes. However, because this is a java.io List, it's saying it won't work.

```
  val files = Option(new java.io.File("data").list).map(_.count(_.endsWith(".csv"))).getOrElse(0)
```

When I try to do

```
files.toDF.show()
```

I get this error:

[image]

How can I get this to work? Can someone help me with the code to convert this java.io List to a regular list?

Thanks

Comment: There is no **SQL** primitive for `Files` - Also, in a distributed environment for which **Spark** is intended to be used `Files` don't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
val files = Option(new java.io.File("data").list).map(_.count(_.endsWith(".csv"))).getOrElse(0)
```

Above Code returns - **Int**, And you are trying to convert **Int** Value to **DataFrame**, How is it possible. If I understand you wanted to convert list of .csv files as DataFrame. Please use this below code -

```
val files = Option(new java.io.File("data").list)).get.filter(x=>x.endsWith(".csv")).toList
import spark.implicits._
files.toDF().show()
```